# How do I set a interval loop function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm trying to create a teleprompter web app with interval loops.

I'm trying to create a tool where the text scrolls up slowly and can be controlled with the play, stop, pause, speed faster, speed slower.

I think I have most of the bits, but I am confused how to set up an interval loop with on clicks.

Any help on this would be great thanks

```js
var tpSpeed = 1

//Places text into Prompter
function startPrompter() {
    var teleprompter = document.getElementById("text").value;
    document.getElementById("script").innerHTML = teleprompter;
}

//Sets loop
myLoop = setInterval(loopFunc, 20)

clearInterval(loopFunc)

clearInterval(myLoop)

tpLooper = setInterval(tpAnimate, 20)


//Scrolls text up
function play(){
 tpScrollTop =  tpScrollTop + tpSpeed;
 $(".scriptContainer").scrollTop(tpScrollTop);
 if(tpScrollTop >= $("#teleprompter").height()){
 //stop when height is reached
 clearInterval(tpLooper);
      }
    }

//Slow down teleprompter
$("#slow").click(function() {
if(tpSpeed>1){
 tpSpeed--;
}
});

//Speed up teleprompter
$("#fast").click(function() {
if(tpSpeed<10){
 tpSpeed++;
}
});


//Starts text scrolling
//$(document).ready(function(){
//    $("#play").click(function(){
//        $("#teleprompter").animate();
//    });
//});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

a{
 color: #00CDCD;
}

body{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #E0E0E0;
 text-align:center;
}

h1{
 font-size: 1.5em; 
}

h2{
 font-size: 1em; 
}

.title{
 background-color: #5D0076;
 color: white;
 text-align:center;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer{
 background-color: #5D0076;
 color: white;
 text-align:center;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 100%;

} 

textarea{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: column;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.container{
 width: 610px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 overflow:hidden;
}

button {
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f9f9f9), color-stop(1, #e9e9e9));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f9f9f9', endColorstr='#e9e9e9',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#f9f9f9;
 -moz-border-radius:6px;
 -webkit-border-radius:6px;
 border-radius:6px;
 border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#666666;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:6px 24px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
button:hover {
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #e9e9e9), color-stop(1, #f9f9f9));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #e9e9e9 5%, #f9f9f9 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e9e9e9', endColorstr='#f9f9f9',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#e9e9e9;
}
button:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}

#text{
 border: 5px solid white; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
      inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
            0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 
      inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
            0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    box-shadow: 
      inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
            0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    padding: 15px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 margin-top: 10px;
 
}
.scriptContainer{
 width: 550px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 5px solid black; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
      inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
            0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 
      inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
            0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    box-shadow: 
      inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
            0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #000000;
 overflow:hidden;
 word-wrap:break-word;
 margin: 0 auto;
 
}

#script{
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 70px;
 font-weight: 700px;
 line-height: 90px;
 text-align:left;
}

.marquee{
 width: 550px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.teleprompter{
   width: 550px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 5px solid black; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
      inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
            0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 
      inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
            0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    box-shadow: 
      inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
            0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #000000;
 overflow:hidden;
 word-wrap:break-word;
 margin: 0 auto;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="wrapper">

<div class="title">
<h1>TELEPROMPTER TOOL</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">

<div id="cover"></div>



<div class="scriptContainer">
<div class="teleprompter" id="teleprompter">

<!--<marquee class="marquee" direction="up" id="script" loop="infinite"></marquee>-->

<p id="script"></p>

</div>
</div>

<div class="controls">

<button class="controls" id="play" onclick="play()" alt="play"><i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i></button>
<button class="controls" id="stop" onclick="stop()" alt="stop"><i class="material-icons">stop</i></button>
<button class="controls" id="pause" onclick="pause()" alt="pause"><i class="material-icons">pause</i></button>
<button class="controls" id="rewind" onclick="rewind()" alt="rewind"><i class="material-icons">fast_rewind</i></button>
<button class="controls" id="slow" onclick="slowDown()" alt="speed slow">Slow down</button>
<button class="controls" id="fast" onclick="speedUp()" alt="speed fast">Speed up</button>

</div>

<p>Please type of copy and paste your script in the text box</p>

<textarea cols="77" rows="20" id="text" value="Input Script Here"></textarea>



</div>

<div class="footer">
<button onclick="startPrompter()">Start Prompter</button>
</div>

</form>

</div>
```

Comment: several of your functions appear not to be part of your question (im looking at you `loopFunc` and `tpAnimate`)

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use recursive timeouts on which a girl can set the interval anew on each turn. Here is a small example on how one could handle those events (comments in code):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            //Just some namespace
            var MyStuff = {
                Teleprompter: {
                    _Interval: 5000, //This is our current interval
                    _Timeout: 0, //This is our timeout-object

                    //This is the function which gets called on each turn/interval
                    _Turn: function(){
                        /*
                        Put whatever you see fit here, scrolling to top or w/e.
                        */
                        document.querySelector('ins').textContent = new Date().getTime() + ' (' + this._Interval + ')';

                        this.Pause(); //Cleanup
                        this.Play() //The whole loop starts again
                    },

                    //To decrease the interval (=faster)
                    Faster: function(){
                        this._Interval = Math.max(1000, this._Interval-1000); //Cant drop below one second
                        this.Play() //Also calls play - in case its not running yet
                    },

                    //To pause and/or stop the interval
                    Pause: function(){
                        window.clearTimeout(this._Timeout);
                        delete this._Timeout
                    },

                    //To start the timeout, if not already running
                    Play: function(){
                        this._Timeout = this._Timeout || window.setTimeout(function(){MyStuff.Teleprompter._Turn()}, this._Interval)
                    },

                    //To increase the interval (=slower)
                    Slower: function(){
                        this._Interval = Math.min(10000, this._Interval+1000); //Cant go above ten seconds
                        this.Play() //Also calls play - in case its not running yet
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <b onclick = 'MyStuff.Teleprompter.Slower()'>Slower</b>
        <b onclick = 'MyStuff.Teleprompter.Faster()'>Faster</b>
        <b onclick = 'MyStuff.Teleprompter.Play()'>Play</b>
        <b onclick = 'MyStuff.Teleprompter.Pause()'>Pause</b>

        <ins></ins>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did this help or does the issue remain?